# JTextfield edit in insert mode - swing

Tags: swing, jtextfield

I have a jtextfield in my app that every time you edit it
i.e. put the mouse in the center of the text and write -
it replaces the letters instead of inserting them.

Is there a way to change this behaviour to insert mode? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code I can only guess that somewhere you have

`textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER)`

which will put the mouse in the center and that maybe you're calling

`textField.replaceSelection()` when the field gain focus or every time the text is changed.